# Android MediaRecorder - record video without audio

Tags: android, android-studio, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

How I can record video only with MediaRecorder? I found the solution that simply leaving out the AudioSource will do that but unfortunately doesn't work on Android 10+. If I do that MediaRecorder.prepare() fails. I can't find a solution on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your media recorder in the following sequence.
Only set AudioSource and AudioEncoder if you want to record with sound.

```
     MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    if (recordWithSound == true) {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    if (recordWithSound == true) {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(videoBitRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFrameRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFile);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done that i have mute mic on button click if you want to mute when recording start than paste the code in your startRecording()

```
    val audioManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audioManager.isMicrophoneMute = false
```